# Как создать виртуальный сервер (host) в Tomcat 9.0.30

Tags: tomcat

С помощью графического интерфейса (кнопка Host Manager стартовой страницы) создал хост **lab** в папке **$CATALINA_HOME/hosts**. Среда создала соответствующие папки в **/conf**, **/works** и **$CATALINA_HOME** (корневой папке Tomcat). В файл **server.xml** добавил:

```
<Host name="lab" appBase="hosts/lab" deployOnStartup="true" />
```

Только после этого новый хост стал сохраняться в списке после перезагрузки Tomcat.
Кнопка сохранения настроек не помогала. В папке **hosts/lab** создал папку **WEB-INF**.
В ней файл **web.xml**:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
 <display-name>My Web Application</display-name>
  <description>
    This is version X.X of an application to perform
    a wild and wonderful task, based on servlets and
    JSP pages.  It was written by Dave Developer
    (dave@mycompany.com), who should be contacted for
    more information.
  </description>
<context-param>
  <param-name>webmaster</param-name>
  <param-value>myaddress@mycompany.com</param-value>
  <description>
    The EMAIL address of the administrator to whom questions
    and comments about this application should be addressed.
  </description>
</context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Шаблон взял в официальной справке. Массу закомментированных строк опускаю.
Ну и поместил в **/lab** простой файл **index.htm** типа "Hello World".
На запрос в браузере `http://localhost:8080/lab` Tomcat выдает статус 404.
Что еще нужно сделать, чтобы хост работал?

Думал, логи помогут. Изменил нод Host:

```
 <Host name="lab" appBase="hosts/lab" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
         <Alias>www.lab</Alias>
          <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" 
            directory="logs"
            prefix="lab_access_log" suffix=".txt"
            pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
  </Host>
```

Теперь при запросе `http://localhost:8080/lab` создается файл lab_access_log.txt, но он пустой.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Ключевой момент для Windows: в файл Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts добавил строку: `127.0.0.1 lab`
В этом был камень преткновения. В серверах под РНР прописывать домен в ОС не приходилось.
Еще нюанс: индексный файл должен быть в папке ROOT (в моем случае: hosts/lab/ROOT/).
Это весь необходимый минимум для создания виртуального хоста.
Браузер: `lab:8080`